# EntityBase and IAggregateRoot Reference not found?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, repository-design

I am trying build a repository, so I found [**this link**](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/12/creating-data-repository-using-dapper.html) explained very well but I got error

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'EntityBase' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'IAggregateRoot' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**My Code is**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace DapperAndSQLite
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
    {
        void Add(T item);
        void Remove(T item);
        void Update(T item);
        T FindByID(Guid id);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
    }
}
```

Here is **Screenshot** (To show the assembly or something is missing)

[image]

Am I missing Something ?

Comment: You need to add this interface and EntityBase in your project. Get them from here https://github.com/bbraithwaite/SmsQuiz/tree/master/src/BB.SmsQuiz.Infrastructure/Domain

Comment: @vendettamit : You can add answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added the Interface `IAggregateRoot` and `EntityBase` in your project. Referenced article has source code hosted on github [here](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/SmsQuiz).

Add the interface and base class from [here](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/SmsQuiz/tree/master/src/BB.SmsQuiz.Infrastructure/Domain).

Answer (score 1):

1) You should never and ever put repository interfaces at **Infrastructure** projects, they belong to **Domain**.

2) This **EntityBase** and the **IAggregateRoot** should stay inside the **Domain** project.

3) You must add **Domain** project Reference to the **Infrastructure.DapperAndSQLite** and implement this repositories.